# How to combine two columns into one?

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following data
Item 1, no attribute
Item 2, attribute A
Item 3, attribute C
Item 4, no attribute
Item 5, attribute B

I have extracted the above information from the web by using the importxml function and it just returns three results in three rows {A,C,B}. I have made a 5x2 table and identified those items that do not have an attribute by putting "-" in the corresponding rows. What formula can I use to generate a column that gives me 5 rows {-,A,C,-B}?

Many thanks in advance.

Link below (Basically I have column A and column C and want to generate column F by using a formula)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1monlmOHLCBlXV40SE0rYcrwB-6TRKvWQAqd7rALK-tk/edit?usp=sharing

I have used arrayformula but then my google sheets knowledge is very limited...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(C2:C6,lambda(Σ,if(Σ<>"",Σ,index(A2:A4,countblank(C2:Σ)))))
```

[image]

Comment: I have no idea what your function means but this is exactly what I need. Million thanks!!!!